# Eclipse C Unit Testing with Check undefined reference error

Tags: c, eclipse, unit-testing, linker-errors, check-framework

I'm extremely new to C and I'm having the following problem: I made a very small program filecopy.c, and I want to make a unit test for it with Check, but when I make the unit test and build it I get a ton of undefined reference errors as if Eclipse cannot find the library libcheck (which I specified by adding 'check' to project - properties - C++ build - settings - libraries).

Here is the relevant code from my files:

filecopy.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fileCopy()
{
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

filecopy.h

```
int fileCopy();
```

filecopyTest.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <check.h>
#include "filecopy.h"

START_TEST (test_fileCopy)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    putchar(i);
}
fileCopy();
//Fail if the last char put by fileCopy is not 9
fail_unless(getchar()==9);
}
END_TEST

Suite *
fileCopy_suite (void)
{
  Suite *s = suite_create ("fileCopy");

  /* Core test case */
  TCase *tc_core = tcase_create ("Core");
  tcase_add_test (tc_core, test_fileCopy);
  suite_add_tcase (s, tc_core);

  return s;
}

 int
 main (void)
 {
 int number_failed;
  Suite *s = fileCopy_suite ();
  SRunner *sr = srunner_create (s);
  srunner_run_all (sr, CK_NORMAL);
  number_failed = srunner_ntests_failed (sr);
  srunner_free (sr);
  return (number_failed == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
```

The test code is exactly as it should be according to the [check tutorial](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_3.html#SEC4), and the filecopy program works on its own. Here is the Makefile that Eclipse generated using this setup:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: Homework1

# Tool invocations
Homework1: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Linker'
    gcc -o "Homework1" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES) Homework1
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

I tell Eclipse to build the filecopy.c file and then to build the filecopyTest.c file, and it gives me an 'undefined reference to [function_name]' for every function called inside of filecopyTest.c (including fileCopy which makes no sense because it includes the header for that function and it doesn't even have to import a library). The library file is in fact present in /usr/lib and installed properly (when running gcc manually, it compiles fine and seems to run (although maybe with some errors; it's difficult to tell)).

Please help if you have any experience with unit testing with C inside Eclipse. I very much love Eclipse and want to use it for my new C projects, but I also love test-first programming and do not intend to develop projects for C without tests in them. I had this exact same problem with CUnit and thought maybe Check would work better, but it's clearly something I'm doing wrong that as a COMPLETE C noob I do not understand. I have scoured the internet and found multiple 'SOLVED' articles on similar situations, but implementing their solutions did not help me on Eclipse. I don't understand what Eclipse does with the make file or even fully what linking is and how it can fail, but I just want to program C in Eclipse with unit testing, and after hours trying to solve this problem, it seems like an insurmountable task. Please let me know if you need additional information; I'm using Eclipse Indigo for reference, which uses CDT 8.0.2.

Thank you in advance for any help anyone might be able to give me. It's so depressing to learn about unit testing and how useful it is and then learn about C and how performant it is and then learn that I can't put the two together inside my favorite IDE.